# TextView not wrapping to multiline

Tags: android, textview

I have a `TextView` inside a `LinearLayout` which displays only a part of its text without wrapping to a newline and cannot understand why. It doesn't even show the ellipsis somewhere.

The `TextView`

```
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/import_progress_text"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:maxLines="4"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        style="@style/TxtDefault" />
```

i also tried `layout_weight=0` along with `layout_height=0` but still no luck. All the siblings inside the `LinearLayout` have `layout_height=wrap_content` set.

**EDIT**

Okay apparently it works when a fixed width is set, but neither with `fill_parent` nor with `match_parent`. Is this the expected behaviour?

**Per Request the whole layout**
Note that inside the FrameLayout is another invisible one, which is rather long

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
style="@style/ContentBody"
>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/progress"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/import_progress_title"
        style="@style/TxtTitle" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="410dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/import_progress_text"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:maxLines="4"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        style="@style/TxtDefault" />

    <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="410dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar_view"
        android:progress="2"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/import_progress_start"
        android:id="@+id/progress_text_view"
        style="@style/TxtSecondary" />

</LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Textview layout_width should be "wrap_content"

Answer (score 0):

if you want to always show text in `n` lines, just add `android:lines="n"`,
or if it's not work, try to use for your `TextView` ->
`android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"`

hope that will help.

Answer (score -1):

The code snippet is wrapping to multiline perfectly. There might be some problem with the IDE, which is not previewing properly. Test on a real device.

Comment: Oh i just realized that the preview looks fine... Only on device it does not work.

Comment: Then it is a device compatability issue. Try using Android Studio inbuilt emulators to test on various devices like Galaxy, Nexus.